# What good alternatives to Poedit are there?

Tags: translation, gettext, poedit

I'm looking for a .po/.mo editor. I am using gettext for the translation files but don't really like Poedit. It has to run on Windows Vista and it would be even better if it was built into Visual Studio 2008 so I could develop and translate.

I really want something that helps me translate and makes translation easier. I want to have suggestions and a spell check.

[No option?
If there really are no options I might as well do something about it and code something so translating is easy again. You could even integrate http://dict.leo.org or see what Google Translate has to offer for the Query. ]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[GTed](http://www.gted.org/) is an interesting alternative for PoEdit.

[image: GTed]

Since it is an Eclipse plugin, it suppose first the installation of eclipse: it is not a stand-alone application. But still, it can do the job.

Comment: Looks good, but how can you parse the sourcecode to get all the translation-source-strings? This tool may only edit exitsing .po files,  but can't generate them from Source, right ?!

Comment: @suther I don't think so, but I don't even know if it it still compatible with the latest Eclipse: that was 5 years ago.

Comment: Ohh, ok. I don't see the date of the posting. So no Problem, I got my poEdit up and running with zf2, so I'll better use this. This seems to be the best choice for translation anyway.

Answer (score 57):

Here are some good alternatives to [Poedit](http://poedit.net):

## Translation editors

- [Lokalize](http://userbase.kde.org/Lokalize): for KDE users ([KBabel](http://kbabel.kde.org/) is now obsolete).
- [GTranslator](http://gtranslator.sourceforge.net/): for GNOME users.
- [GTed](http://www.gted.org/)<sub>dead link</sub>: runs everywhere Eclipse runs.
- [Virtaal](https://virtaal.translatehouse.org/): Windows, Linux, Mac.  Good choice for GNOME users.

## Text editor

- Vim: you can use the [Vim script for po files Editing](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=695)
- Emacs: you can use [po mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/gettext/PO-Mode.html#PO-Mode) to do your editing.

## Other notes

There's a php application that would be useful for collaborative editing. Actually synchronizing with a subversion system would solve the problem anyways with any of these tools. However, if anyone does remember more applications, feel free to add.

Comment: didn't I mention I wanted something for vista?

Comment: GTranslator is great. Perfect

Comment: Please change the "Url" of Virtaal. It is https://virtaal.translatehouse.org/ and not virtaal.org (Spam page)

Comment: I changed the link. The old link indeed was spam link.

Answer (score 7):

Just for reference: [Google Translator Toolkit](http://translate.google.com/toolkit/) allows translation of po-Files [since 2012](http://google-opensource.blogspot.de/2012/03/localize-your-apps-and-content-more.html). I never really used it though.

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't appear to support PO files anymore.

Comment: Translator Toolkit is now discontinued. Clicking the link just redirects to a support document.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest [Virtaal](http://virtaal.org) which is cross-platform and very simple to setup and use yet very powerful.

Comment: It doesn't parse your source files though. Just saying.

Comment: I found this to be the least painful option. It generally gets out of your way, doesn't force you to learn its own workflow and is one of the few editors that lets you easily add terms beyond what it finds in the template.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [poeditor.com](http://www.poeditor.com). Looks nice and does what we need in terms of collaboration.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working with [Transifex](http://www.transifex.net) for a while. It's not really a good editor as such, but a collaborative platform for translations. They have reasonable editing facilities online. It also allows you to pull translations down to work with them locally, so I'd also love to see a good editor.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you might consider using [Bettter PO Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/betterpoeditor/)  or [gorm](http://gorm.po.dk/).

Answer (score 0):

[LocFactory](http://www.triplespin.com/en/products/locfactoryeditor.html) is another alternative - sorry, it's OSX only, but it might be useful to others reading this post.

Unfortunately I've found poEdit to be the best of a pretty bad bunch. I'd love to find a replacement.

Comment: LocFactory seems to be dead according to an email conversation with Mike Butler, mainly because of the Apple Java/Cocoa debacle.