# Which PO editor can extract messages from twig files?

Tags: twig, gettext

There is a lot of PO editors, you can find some of them here: [What good alternatives to poEdit are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393267/what-good-alternatives-to-poedit-are-there)

But which one can extract messages from twig files?

```
{% trans %}Hello %name%{% endtrans %}
```

There is some way to use poedit, but I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no PO editor that can parse Twig emplates. Poedit can do it with the help of Twig Gettext Extractor.

The [Twig Gettext Extractor](https://github.com/umpirsky/Twig-Gettext-Extractor) is [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/download.php) friendly tool which extracts translations from twig templates.

Comment: OK, can you define what is "better way" for you? What is wrong with current ways?

Comment: there are about 20 PO editors, you can find them in referred link in question. Which one can extract strings from twig files. independent from `Symfony framework`

Comment: I think there is no PO editor that can do that. Poedit can do it with the help of Twig Gettext Extractor.

Comment: I wrote [a grunt task](https://github.com/gwa/grunt-gettext-parser) to extract gettext calls from twig templates to a php file that poedit can read.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following two npm modules [xgettext-template](https://github.com/gmarty/xgettext) and [gettext-volt](https://github.com/perchlayer/gettext-volt). Works perfectly since Volt templates have nearly the same syntax as Twig templates.

**EDIT 2021:**

You could also purchase a [Poedit Pro licence](https://poedit.net/pro):

> **Work with Twig and Volt templates**
> Twig is one of the most popular templating languages for web development, used by WordPress, Craft CMS, Symfony, Drupal, or Grav; Volt is used by Phalcon. Poedit Pro supports extraction of translation strings from Twig and Volt templates out of the box.

Comment: A bit of source code as a reference point would be handy

Comment: @AlexanderKucheryuk: what source code? All you need is described in the README of xgettext-template.