# User friendly tool for internationalization in CakePHP 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization

I have a multi language website written in CakePHP 1.3 and I'm currently in the process of adding a new language. I have the original .pot file and I generated a new .po file for the given language. So far so good, it's all working, however, now someone has to do the actual translation. I've send them the relevant .po file with explanations what to do but they seem to have problems dealing with plain text file. Is there a user friendly tool or piece of code that would actually allow them to translate the phrases one by one, without having to deal with text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a po editor. There are many out there for various platforms. Some free, some not. They usually provide a simple interface for viewing all the available translation strings and adding the translation next to them without need for viewing the po file in a text editor. My understanding is that many translators are familiar with this type of software so may already have one installed.

Check out this Stack Overflow question and answers for suggestions:-

[What good alternatives to poEdit are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393267/what-good-alternatives-to-poedit-are-there)

Comment: Thank you, seems that there is plenty of information in that other post!