# Finding missing translations in django `.po` files

Tags: django, internationalization, locale, gettext

Working with Django, you can use `django.utils.translation.ugettext` and `....ugettext_lazy` (as well as some template tags) to handle translation of localized messages.

Later, with command: `django-admin.py makemessages -l <LANGUAGE>` you can generate the `po` file containing the original string, so that the developer can specify the desired translation.

Question: is there a django command, or any other quick way, to find out which messages have not been translated?

Usually I look for the string `msgstr ""` in the `po` file, but that's inaccurate, since some translations are multiline, like the following:

```
#file.py:xyz
msgid ""
"Some very long text"
msgstr ""
"The translation of some very long text"
```

Thus, looking for `msgstr ""` I get "false positives" (i.e. strings that are actually translated, but whose translation start the next line). With thousand of lines, this quite often.

Any smart suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: From what I've seen, django seems to put then untranslated to the top (or possibly the bottom can't remember) of the list of translations

Comment: No, I don't think so. I find them in the middle of my `po` file :-/

Comment: Hmm, I can't remember then, our translators switched over to using Poedit which kind of negates this entire problem

Comment: Don't know what IDE you are using, but in PyCharm you can search by regex: `""\n\n` this highlights all untranslated entries.

Comment: In PyCharm adding newline field to search can be done with Crtl +Shift + Enter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using some popular editors:

- in most editors, simply search `msgstr ""\n\n`
- under windows / with notepad, maybe you will need something like `msgstr ""\r\n\r\n`
- you could also try some specialized editors, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393267/what-good-alternatives-to-poedit-are-there)
- ultimatively, you could do the following: `sed -i '/msgstr ""/{N;N; s/\n\n/\n# translate me!\n\n/g}' django.po` and then search for `# translate me!` comments in the file.

Comment: Oops. Just realized that the last one was broken. Whatever, made another one.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```sh
msgfmt --statistics --output=/dev/null locale/django.po
```

to see how many missing translations there are (if any), and

```sh
msgattrib --untranslated locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

to list the untranslated messages.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to check for missing translations, and other errors, would be to use the "msgcmp" utility. It's actually supposed to be used to compare a translations file (.po) against a template (.pot), but it's perfectly happy to compare a .po file against itself:

```sh
msgcmp path/to/nl.po path/to/nl.po
```

will do the trick, and even fail if any translations are marked as fuzzy (unless you specify --use-fuzzy).