# i18n support for Golang Web application HTML templates

Tags: go, web, internationalization, go-gin

Does anyone has a good idea to localize HTML templates in Golang Web application? Now I'm using Gin and [go-i18n](https://github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n), but I will use other frameworks if they can localize.

If possible, I want to define the localized messages in property (or JSON/yaml/toml,...) files for each language:

```
label.password = パスワード # Password in Japanese
```

and write localized html like Thymeleaf:

```html
<label th:text="#{label.password}"></label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chose to use [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) instead of go-i18n because the message keys can be embedded in HTML and replaced with language JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

[Spreak](https://github.com/vorlif/spreak) supports template localization by passing a localizer as template data.
It can also automatically extract the strings to be translated.

The process is similar to that of go-i18n.
Create your templates:

```html
<label>{{.T.Get "Password"}}</label>
```

Load the translations:

```golang
bundle, err := spreak.NewBundle(
    spreak.WithSourceLanguage(language.English),
    // Set the path from which the translations should be loaded
    spreak.WithDomainPath(spreak.NoDomain, "locale"),
    // Specify the languages you want to load
    spreak.WithLanguage(language.Japanese, language.German),
)
```

Create a localizer for a request and pass it as template data.

```golang
func(c *gin.Context) {
    accept := c.GetHeader("Accept-Language")
    localizer := spreak.NewLocalizer(bundle, accept)
    
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "template.html", gin.H{
        "T": localizer,
    })
}
```

Use xspreak to extract the strings to be translated.

```sh
go install github.com/vorlif/xspreak@latest
xspreak -D path/to/code -o path/to/code/locale/base.pot --template-prefix "T" -t "templates/*.html"
```

A directory `locale` with a file `base.pot` is created.
The file is the template for new translations and contains the strings to be translated in `po`-format. The structure of the file follows the structure:

```
#: ../template.html:8
#, go-template
msgid "Password"
msgstr ""
```

For editing, it is best to use an editor like [PoEdit](https://poedit.net/), but there are also [many good alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393267/what-good-alternatives-to-poedit-are-there) and online platforms.

Open the file `base.pot` with an editor and create your `.po` files with the translations.
In your example, this would be the file `locale/ja.po` with the structure

```
#: ../template.html:8
#, go-template
msgid "Password"
msgstr "パスワード"
```

Start the application and the matching translations will be used. The original text will be displayed if there are no matching translations.

I also created [a full example](https://github.com/vorlif/spreak/tree/main/examples/features/httptempl) using `.i18n.Tr` as translation method in the templates and using multiple languages.

Note: I am the author of spreak.